# PyQt use QStyle.StandardPixmap with QIcon

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using `pyqt4` and I want to replace the displayed icon in tree view:

```
if typeInfo == "LIGHT":
    return QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Light.png"))
```

I would like to use `PyQt` Standard Pixmap items ([here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum)), something like:

```
if typeInfo == "LIGHT":
    return QtGui.QStyle.SP_DirClosedIcon
```

But the icon is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked to leads to the answer:

```
    return QtGui.qApp.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DirClosedIcon)
```

Comment: I was trying something like `return QtGui.QStyle.standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DirClosedIcon)`. Looks I just had to change `QtGui.QStyle` to `QtGui.QtGui.qApp.style()`